# Postgres function INSERT INTO

Tags: database, function, postgresql, insert-into

I have this function which insert into an account some values.
If the function will find on my DB a tuple with the number(i) already picked the transation abort.

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert(num integer) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..num LOOP
    BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Insert account %', i; -- print i
    INSERT INTO Account VALUES (i,NULL,0);
END;
END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT *
FROM INSERT
```

---

Now I want to modify this function in order to make persistent the insertions before the number i, my idea was to add COMMIT after the INSERT INTO but it doesn't worked.

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert1(num integer) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..num LOOP
    BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Insert account %', i; -- print i
    INSERT INTO Account VALUES (i,NULL,0);
    COMMIT;
END;
END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Could you please help me ?
Best regards.

Filippo

Comment: A function call is already transaction safe, everything gets committed or everything is rolled back. And thus you can't commit within a function.

Comment: Are you looking for autonomous commit? PostgreSQL doesn't have that yet, though you can emulate them (badly) with dblink.

Comment: It will probably be easier to first check whether the tuple you're trying to insert already exists in the database.

Comment: BTW: why not just use `generate_series()` instead of a hand-coded loop?

Comment: So I can't partially insert some values ?